# How to change scale a .urdf model

Tags: unity-game-engine, ros, unity3d-editor, urdf

I'm trying to import a urdf into another project. It completely changes behavior when it is scaled.

So I have imported a urdf model into unity using the urdf importer. I have added scripts to it all of it works completely fine when the scale is (1,1,1) but now I have to import it into the main project. There is an already existing scene and i have to scale my model to (50,50,50) to match the scene. this completely breaks the model and behaves completely different.
I have a 6 joint gripper robot. It has stiffness, damping, forcelimit, spped, torque and acceleration parameters that I have to set after lots of trial and error and i got the perfect values for the (1,1,1) scaled robot. Using these same values just causes the robot to collapse. I have tried so many different configurations of parameters but still no luck.
So is there any way to scale the model without affecting its other properties?
Note: I cannot reduce the scale of the main project to fit the robot due to other reasons

TLDR: increasing size/scaling the urdf model changes its properties/behavior